# Qt Creator project won't build on windows (linker error)

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I have a working project on Linux (Ubuntu 11.04), but when i try to build the same exact code on my Windows 7 machine, I get the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'windows_wminput.c'
```

The project I'm working on uses a C library called [ManyMouse](http://icculus.org/manymouse/). I have included the .c files in my .pro file as follows:

```
LIBS += windows_wminput.c \
linux_evdev.c \
x11_xinput2.c \
macosx_hidmanager.c \
macosx_hidutilities.c
```

Again, this project/setup works fine on Linux, but gives an error on Windows. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should have `SOURCES` instead of `LIBS`.

Comment: And the reason it works on Linux is that `g++` can accept both object files and source files (which it compiles and links together if it's called to link a final binary file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, after some fiddling around it now works on Windows too.